# Direct/None Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I have a website that has google analytics. I got Direct/None when I view my ALL TRAFFICS. Is there a code or way to prevent this to go up? and be specific where people get my website?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it? People who type in your URL manually are still perfectly legitimate visitors.

Comment: because my traffic is high and I don't think that people already recognize my site. I want it to be specific.

Comment: If Google Analytics could tell you where those people were coming from, they would. Chances are it's perfectly real traffic. You can't much affect how GA tracks these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

A way to "prevent" a high number of Direct/None would be to check for redirects, if this feels like an unexpected behavior. GA might lose referrer data for campaigns if the web server doesn't redirect properly. And by properly I mean it also redirects any eventual campaign tracking URLs.

The question is very vague, so please clarify.